# How multicasting grouping address works ? How can I add nodes to the existing group of multicasting group?

Tags: networking, ipv6, multicast

I am a newbie to the networking and working on the [6LoWPAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6LoWPAN) protocol and I am trying to get the multicasting to work on the network. But I don't know how to create group for multicasting and how to provide a group ID to the device which wants to join the multicast group.

Comment: I have no idea about the subtleties of 6LoWPAN and I think most of others who would know about multicast setups, might miss this bit too. Could you elaborate on your case a bit more? Do you have routed multicasts or local-subnet-only multicasts? Do you manage the routers and are you using dynamic multicast routing along with PIM as the registration protocol? Do you need a programmer's view on this so you would have an idea about which APIs to call to make the client register with a multicast group?

Answer (score 1):

Broadly, when you want to use IPv6 multicast, your hosts can simply join multicast groups ad-hoc by sending an MLPv2 ICMPv6 message (RFC3810) to the multicast routers multicast address FF02::16.  If you are using 6LoWPAN to build a mesh network, I believe all your devices would also need to support MLPv2 as routers as well as hosts.

Without knowing more about your platform and what exact task you are trying to accomplish, this is as far as I can take you.  I don't believe there is a de facto standard utility set for this in linux, and if you're developing an embedded device either your platform will have an API for this or you will have to implement it from the RFC.

Multicast groups are created implicitly when a host joins one, and the multicast address functions as a group ID.  These are fundamental intrinsics of the design of IP multicast.

Comment: I am using nanostack from Sensinode to develope the sensor network. I am using the Kit from the atmel for this sensor network. I dont know how to multicast the packet since the document provided by them doesnt mention anything about multicast. I am able to use the unicasting.

Comment: Their SDK might not support it.  In any case, I don't think this relates to server administration (I've no idea where this might be on topic).